# Convert UTF-8 multibyte characters into multiple ascii characters

Tags: ruby, utf-8, ascii

Can someone help me with converting some (potential) bogus UTF-8 multibyte characters into ascii as follows?

`\u6162` → `["\x61", "\x62"]` → `["a", "b"]` → `"ab"`

My use case is fun only. I know I'm not compressing anything by representing two ascii characters in a multibyte character.

I've played around with various versions of `unpack` but it never seems to work correctly:

```
"\u6162".unpack('H*')
# => ["e685a2"]
```

Force encoding seems to return the same:

```
"\u6162".force_encoding('US-ASCII')
# => "\xE6\x85\xA2"
```

Answer (score 2):

`"\u6162"` is not equivalent to `"\x61" + "\x62"`.  `\u` indicates a Unicode code point which does not translate directly to a hex value.  [Unicode code point 6162 is 慢](https://codepoints.net/U+6162).

Because it is a string, and because Ruby uses UTF-8 by default, when you unpack it you get the UTF-8 value of U+6162 which is three bytes: `E6 85 A2`.

```
2.2.1 :023 > "\u6162".encoding
 => #<Encoding:UTF-8> 
2.2.1 :024 > "\u6162".unpack("A*")
 => ["\xE6\x85\xA2"]
```

To get what you want, you need its UTF-16 representation `61 62`.  But if you just encode as `UTF-16` you'll get a byte order marker `FE FF 61 62`.  So use UTF-16BE (big endian) to avoid this.

```
2.2.1 :052 > "\u6162".encode("UTF-16BE").unpack("A*")
 => ["ab"]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
"\u6162".codepoints.first.divmod(16 ** 2).map(&:chr).join
# => "ab"
```

Comment: Good solution, but downvoted for lack of explanatory text. Also, prefer `pack('c*')` to `map(&:chr).join`.